# Toast.warn render twice on refresh of page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-toastify

I'm facing an issue where the toast message is rendered twice on page load.

The props are being passed with Link

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/administration/person/add`, merchantData: { merchant } }}>Create Person</Link>
```

and another page by grabbing the data with useLocation

```
cons {merchantData} = useLocation();
```

What I want is on page load and when the data is lost, it should give a warning message with the code below.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (merchantData === undefined) {
            toast.warn('Please Select Merchant');
        }
    }, [merchantData]);
```

Comment: Please create a minimal, reproducible example. Post the code to codesandbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an ID to your toast to prevent a duplicate toast from appearing.

```
toast.warn('Please Select Merchant', {
  toastId: "your-id"
});
```

You can learn more in their documentation: https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/prevent-duplicate